# Different "request" implicit objects in Liferay

Tags: java, servlets, attributes, request, liferay

What is the difference between fetching attributes from these implicit objects:

```
renderRequest.getAttribute("myVar")
actionRequest.getAttribute("myVar")
request.getAttribute("myVar")
```

Why are they all allowed?
I mean you usually store attribute in `actionRequest` or `renderRequest` object but you can get it in `request` implicit object, why?
What is the correct approach?

How is it possible to get an action object in view time?
Does not it violate the action-render renderParams passing mechanism?
Why are actionRequest/response available as implicit object if they throw `NullPointerException` when trying to use them in JSP?

Finally when is it useful to store an attribute in the request (`PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**What is the correct approach for accessing request attributes?**
In portlets, the correct approach is to only interact with the `renderRequest` for retrieving parameter values and for getting or setting request attributes (in JSPs or the portlet class). `renderResponse` can be used to create new Portlet URLs.

**Why can you get request attributes from the `request` object as well?**
`request` is an `HttpServletRequest` and `renderRequest` is a `PortletRequest`. However, Liferay implemented `request` as a wrapper of `HttpServletRequest` in such way that, e.g. for accessing request attributes, it will fallback to the `PortletRequest` if it doesn't find the attribute in the actual `HttpServletRequest`.

**What's the use of `actionRequest` and `actionResponse` at view time?**
Like you say, if you follow the principles of MVC, you will only use the JSP for view logic. If you check the `DefineObjectsTag` from Liferay, you can see that all these `xxxRequest` and `xxxResponse` objects are only set if the portlet is in the right lifecycle. Because, normally, you're in the RENDER_PHASE when executing the JSP logic, only `renderRequest` and `renderResponse` will be not-null.

**When is it useful to store an attribute in the `request`?**
It doesn't really make sense to store attributes in the `HttpServletRequest` if you're working with portlets. On the other hand, inside a servlet (filter) you could add attributes that can then be retrieved from portlets by using `request.getAttribute("xxx")`.